# how to fix this error while importing matplotlib?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, importerror

I got this error message while tried to import matplotlib and don't know how to fix it. I tried install again matplotlib with different version, but still not work. I'm using Pycharm with virtual env.

File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/autoencoder_7_4_symbol.py", line 11, in

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 157, in

```
_check_versions()
```

File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 152, in _check_versions

```
if LooseVersion(module.__version__) < minver:
```

AttributeError: module 'dateutil' has no attribute '**version**'

Here's the package
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kyXgOMyq-j3gfBH-PwzqN4pkjT32Cjq1a36E-dY74PU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the env?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kyXgOMyq-j3gfBH-PwzqN4pkjT32Cjq1a36E-dY74PU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add it to the question itself? I'm guessing you obtained that using `conda list` ?

Comment: this can't be opened? I copy this from pycharm setting.

Comment: Have you installed "matplotlip" package in Anaconda or PyCharm? if you didn't do it in PyCharm then try doing that. Here are the steps: from  PyCharm Settings/Preferences/Project:pythonProject/Python Interpreter/click on add symbol, and then search for "matplotlib" and then click on install package, close the window and try running your code/importing the package.

Comment: I fix this problem temporarily from this website by using 'conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib-base', since when use conda the qt things is still a prohlem.[link]https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10949

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your environment, and you are not the only one who ever had it (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17433)). Reinstall `matplotlib` and, if that does not do the trick, the complete environment.

```
conda activate tensorflow
conda update matplotlib
```

Create environment anew:

```
conda activate tensorflow
conda list -e > req.txt # if you need the build info, use "export"
conda create -n <your-environment-name> --file req.txt
```